# iPad CSS hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, safari

I have a page with 5 sublinks having class "searchBySub"
Now in my CSS I have defined normal, hover states as well as a class for clicked
So we have

```
#leftNav .searchBySub {...}
#leftNav a.searchBySub:hover {...}
#leftNav .searchBySubClicked {...}
```

My Question is when any of these 5 sublinks is clicked on iPad, it goes to the hover state. So is there any way by which I can force it to not go in hover state rather apply the class searchBySubClicked

As the hover state is causing some issues...Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the media queries, but like so http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}
```

You could try to undo the hover state in there. However the ideal supposedly is to create the mobile styles first and then create full screen browser styles afterwards within

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports 768px and over go here */
    #leftNav a.searchBySub:hover {...}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regulate the hovers for screen devices by using media queries in HTML headers. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

in your case try putting the hover in separate screen purpose css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="hover.css" />
```

Comment: I am really not sure how media queries would help here...My Question is when I tap on any of the links I want the class which it takes should be a.searchBySubClicked and not a.searchBySub:hover

Comment: Media queries will prevent iPad seeing the hover at all. I doubt there is any other way to stick hover only to non-iPad without using css hacks (which are evil by default) since touch devices should not trigger hover in first place . So either media detection or javascript (detect string 'iPad' in navigator.userAgent and prevent hover event)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the JavaScript way, you could use jQuery mobile http://jquerymobile.com/ and raise click events that add your class.
Regular jQuery leads to issues, because it doesn't accept touch events, the apple-hardware triggers

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to include modernizr in your build, which will add a touch/no-touch class to your <html> tag. Then you can target the :hover tag to only be relevant to no-touch devices:

```
#leftNav .searchBySub {...)
.no-touch #leftNav a.searchBySub:hover {...}
#leftNav .searchBySubClicked {...}
```

http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found out (by accident) that when the element triggering the `:hover` state has **CSS transitions** applied, then iOS appears to ignore the hover state and triggers the click instead.

In my case I actually *wanted* the hover state to work but couldn't get it to work until I removed the transitions (or excluded them specifically on iOS).  Can post some sample code if anyone would like.